# Access from unknown IP tracks to non-existent website

Tags: linux-mint, apt, ip, remote, traceroute

Just had a warning that my Gmail's been accessed from the following IP: `151.230.107.114` which routes to something called htc_frisbee.com , which doesn't appear to be a real website. Could this just be a proxy for my phone, and is the `traceroute` I ran useful in any way? Could anyone suggest other apps, particularly ones accessible from `Linux Mint` and the `apt-get` command, which might help work out where this access came from?

Comment: Are you syncing your contacts between your phone and Google (consciously or otherwise)?

Comment: They are being synced, yeah, but my phone uses the same wi-fi as my laptop. It should have the same I, shouldn't it?

Comment: This is probably some OEM bullshit service that HTC installed to snoop^H^H^H add value to the mobile experience...

Comment: To get some more relevant help, please provide: `traceroute -n 151.230.107.114`, `host 151.230.107.114` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address `151.230.107.114` is a dynamical one which belongs to Sky Broadband. You can see this from:

```
whois 151.230.107.114
```

Sky Broadband is a United Kingdom ISP.

What Google is indicating you is the fact that the last time you connected to them, this was from this IP address and it is different from your usual one. This is the main reason of this warning.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm interested in understanding why the trace goes through htc_frisbee.com . The Google warning was suggesting that the account had been access from a new location. Perhaps a proxy for my own broadband, perhaps not. That's what I'm interested in finding out.

Comment: @Peter David Carter: From my ISP, the `traceroute` doesn't go to `htc_frisbee.com`. Moreover, `htc_frisbee.com` isn't a corect host name on the DNS. Something is (or was) wrong with your DNS resolving.